# Searching for location by name in Instagram API

Tags: ios, swift, location, instagram-api

I am using Instagram API for iOS. I'd like to search for location by name exactly like in the Instagram app itself but the only endpoint available for searching for location is by LAT and LONG.

Is there a way to make it like the Instagram app itself makes it, where you search for location by typing the name?

THX!

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar but I had to code it myself. I used a `searchBar` to get a location and pin the location as an `annotation` to a `MapView` I used the `annotation` coordinates to preform the search. I was intentionally displaying the map and pin. Here is the code I used.

```
         // do search for locations 
         localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest() 
         localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text 
         localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest) 
         localSearch.start { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in 


             // alert if location not found 
             if localSearchResponse == nil{ 
                 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Place Not Found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert) 
                 alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)) 
                 self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
                 activityIndicator.hide() 
                 return 
             } 

             // append annotation if result is found 
             self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation() 
             self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text 
             // get pin location 
             self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude) 


             self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil) 
             self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate 


             self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
```

If you don't intend to use a `mapView` you could still use this code to get the locations Lat and Long

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:
                       localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude,
                       longitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I am looking for, this would mean that I need to use 2 endpoints, first one to get the location and then to use the Instagram one to pinpoint the location by the lat long I got from the previous search. Do you know about something where I could do it only with calling just one endpoint?

Comment: Not off the top of my head but I'll read through the API when I have some time and circle back to this thread if I find something that you're looking for.